# Access field parent in custom JsonValidator

Tags: c#, .net, json.net, jsonschema

I'm using Newtonsoft's excellent JsonSchema lib and attempting to build a custom validator for a `greaterthanfield` another field validation.

In order to do this I obviously need to access the other field from the `Validate(JToken value, JsonValidatorContext context)` method. However the `JToken` present doesn't have any parent information to be able to find the required sibling. Likewise the `JsonValidatorContext` doesn't have any reference to the validation data only the schema.

I'd hoped to be able to just:
`value.Parent["siblingkey"]` but it appears the `JToken` is literally just that token without access to the rest of the parsed data.

Does anyone know of a way of implementing such a validator? One that references other fields. Other examples would be something like a `combinedmaxlength` etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have been playing around a little bit, because I ran into the same problem.
I found that the custom validator system has some weird behaviour where the JToken tree is being re-built based on the highest parent node **which your validator can validate** (where CanValidate returns true)

This means that if we can trick the system to believe your validator can validate the root token **and** your specific token, your tree will be hydrated.

```
public class TestValidator : JsonValidator
{

    public override bool CanValidate(JSchema schema)
    {
        // we assume every schema has a title/schemaversion in its root object.
        return schema.Title != null || schema.SchemaVersion != null || schema.ExtensionData.ContainsKey("greaterthanfield");
    }

    public override void Validate(JToken value, JsonValidatorContext context)
    {
        // we should ignore the "root token validation"
        if (!context.Schema.ExtensionData.ContainsKey("greaterthanfield"))
            return;
        // value.Parent is hydrated now
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I just had this issue. I was applying custom validators (using "Format") on the property level which did not work.

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema",
  "title": "JSON Schema for custom rule",

  "type": "object",

  "properties": {
    "Prop1": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "Prop2": {
      "type": "string",
      "format": "YourCustomValidatorName"
    }
  }
}
```

You instead need to apply the custom validator to the entire schema.

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema",
  "title": "JSON Schema for custom rule",

  "type": "object",

  "properties": {
    "Prop1": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "Prop2": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  },

  "format": "YourCustomValidatorName"
}
```

Then in your custom validator class you will be able to access all the properties

```
public override void Validate(JToken value, JsonValidatorContext context)
{
    var prop1 = value.SelectToken("..Prop1")?.Value<string>();
    var prop2 = value.SelectToken("..Prop2")?.Value<string>();

    // Rest of your logic...
}
```

Comment: for a static example, this might work (you compare prop1 to prop2)
when you want to make it generic, this won't work anymore (prop5.nestedprop512 has to be greater than prop1.nestedprop10.subnestedprop90)
therefore this is a terrible solution
(although there doesn't seem to be a real solution to OP's problem...)

Comment: See my answer for a method that should be generic, and is somewhat based on your proposal :-)